# The definition of the addition is continuous on a linear space with a topology?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I saw the definition of topological vector space. Let $X$ be a linear space with a topology such that the map $X\times X\rightarrow X$, $(x,y)\mapsto x+y$ is continuous. It follows that for all $x_1$, $x_2$ $\in$ $X$, if $V$ is a neighborhood of $x_1+x_2$, then there exists a neighborhood $V_i$ of $x_i$ $(i=1,2)$ such that $V_1+V_2\subseteq V$.

How can we get this from the definition of the continuity in a topological space? Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is almost literally the definition.  Have you made any attempt to understand what the definition says?

Comment: @EricWofsey I only know the definition of the continuity in a topological space. How to imply this one?

Comment: You apply the definition of continuity to the addition, which you've assumed continuous, hence this is legal.

Comment: @Randall Thanks for your answer! But what is the neighborhood of $X\times X$?

Comment: @AnswerLee Do you understand the product topology?

Comment: @Randall Not really. Can you give me any clue?

Comment: OK, that's probably the important bit.  A set is open in $X \times X$ if it is expressible as a union $\bigcup_i A_i \times B_i$ where each $A_i$ and $B_i$ is open in $X$.

Comment: @Randall But how it turns to $V_1+V_2$ is the definition?

Comment: You push forward a suitable $V_1 \times V_2$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83255/discussion-between-answer-lee-and-randall).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p: X \times X \to X$ be the map $p(x_1,x_2) = x_1 + x_2$, defined on $X \times X$ with the product topology.

The latter means that a point $(x_1, x_2) \in X \times X$ has basic neighbourhoods that are of the form $V_1 \times V_2$, where $V_1, V_2 \subseteq X$ are open and $x_1 \in V_1, x_2 \in V_2$.

So the standard topological definition of continuity at $(x_1,x_2) \in X \times X$ of $p$ is translated as:

> For every open neighbourhood $V$ of $x_1 + x_2 = p(x_1,x_2)$ there exists a product basic neighbourhood $V_1 \times V_2$ of $(x_1,x_2)$ such that $p[V_1 \times V_2] \subseteq V$.

It then suffices to note that $p[V_1 \times V_2] = \{p(a,b): a \in V_1, b\in V_2\} = \{a+b: a \in V_1, b\in V_2\}  =V_1 + V_2$ by definition. Hence the criterion is explained.